# Can't figure out algorithm to make a N-Letter Word counter C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, c++11, counter

I have been trying to make an algorithm that would read a file "TESTDATA" and then arrange the data in an array that would output something like this

```
ONE LETTER WORDS IN FILE = 1
TWO LETTER WORDS IN FILE = 45
THREE LETTER WORDS IN FILE = 27
FOUR LETTER WORDS IN FILE = 12
```

I'm not asking for an exact code, I just can't figure out how to approach this problem as I am very new to c++.

here is what I've done uptill now, I can only read the file;

```
ifstream fin("file.txt");
if (fin.is_open())
{
    while (getline(fin, string str))
    {
       cout << fileline << endl;
    }
    fin.close();
```

Comment: I have not attempted it as I do not the proper approach, that is what I am asking, I have read the file and I can show the output but that is just about it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use either a `std::vector` or a `std::map`.  The vector is more efficient accessing, but requires overhead to get it started.

```
std::string word;
std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> data;
/...
while (fin >> word)
{
  const unsigned int length = word.length();
  data[length]++;
}
```

The lengths and the number of words with those lengths can be printed out using `std::map` iterators.  This is left as an exercise for the reader and OP.

**Edit 1: Vectors**
With a vector, the word length will be used as an index.  The number of occurrences is accessed by using the word length.

```
std::string word;
std::vector<unsigned int> data(128); // Reserve space for up to 128 length words.
// ...
while (fin >> word)
{
  const unsigned int length = word.length();
  data[length]++;
}
// To print:
// ...
   cout << index << " letter words in file: " << data[index] << "\n";
//...
```

Comment: Thanks a million! I'm going to try this out and see if I have any more questions

Answer (score 0):

So essentially what you want to do is read in the whole file, and then split the file by spaces (" ") into a Vector. Then you can simply write a quick for loop saying something like this (syntax may not be perfect):

```
for (int i=0;i<vec.size;i++){
    cout << vec[i].length(); //number of letters in each word
}
```

Comment: is there any way I can avoid vectors and maps? as I am not familiar with them or this is the only efficient way?

Comment: You could, yes, but a vector is truly very simple to use. 5 minutes of reading and you could do everything I just talked about above.

Comment: Essentially a vector is just making life easier for you, as it is an array which will dynamically allocate memory (don't need to declare size beforehand).

Comment: @xx3987 why avoid them?  Being unfamiliar is not an excuse.  You will only become familiar with them if you use them so you might as well start with this as a map or vector is perfect for this

Comment: okay, so I should make a vector and how would I assign each letter to its space?